# In this code bit, why is there a declaration of (random rand) for the input?

Tags: c#

I apologize that this is lower level, but I am trying to figure this out so I understand. This is the example for C# Random function.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class RandomNumbers
{
   public static void Main()
   {
        Random rand1 = new Random();
        Random rand2 = new Random();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Random rand3 = new Random();
        ShowRandomNumbers(rand1);
        ShowRandomNumbers(rand2);
        ShowRandomNumbers(rand3);
   }

   private static void ShowRandomNumbers(Random rand)
   {
        Console.WriteLine();
        byte[] values = new byte[5];
        rand.NextBytes(values);
        foreach (byte value in values)
            Console.Write("{0, 5}", value);
        Console.WriteLine();   
   }
}
```

I understand calling the Main function and then `ShowRandomNumbers()`, but why call the data type Random for the variable rand in the `ShowRandomNumbers` function? 
Are you declaring another variable, but doing so as the function is being called?

Again if this is a dumb question, I sincerely apologize, but trying to get a grasp on why this is the way it is being written.

Comment: Class types Are passed by reference as Default. and Random is a Class Type. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**Random** is not a variable here. Its class and **rand1, rand2, rand3, rand** are its objects.

And its not declaring another class's object. Its **passing** that **rand** object into the function from the main, that can be further used in the **ShowRandomNumbers**.

Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The function declaration is only telling the function what it will receive, not creating anything new.

To add to Jamel's answer:

The code tries to demostrate how the Random objects `rand1` and `rand2`, which are created **without** a seed, will be seeded from the **system time**; therefore the first two will most likely have the same seed and return the same sequence of numbers while the third one (`rand3`) is ceated two seconds later and will create a different sequenece.

Usually you create only **one** Random object per program.

You can also create a Random number generator object **with** a seed and therby create a repeatable sequence of pseudo-random numbers.